# Equivalent of java finalize method

Tags: go

Is there any method like java finalize in Go? If I've a type struct like

```
    type Foo struct {
        f *os.File
        ....
    }

func (p *Foo) finalize() {
     p.f.close( )           
}
```

How can I make sure that when Object is garbage collected, the file is closed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`runtime.SetFinalizer` iirc. But its considered a bad thing and isn't guaranteed to run before program exit

EDIT: As mentioned below, the current `os` package already calls `runtime.SetFinalizer` on files. However, `SetFinalizer` shouldn't be relied upon. As an example of why, I had a file-server-like application where I forgot to close open file. The process would usually get to about 300 open files before the GC picked them up and called their finalizer.

Comment: If you don't explicitly close an os.File its constructor calls ` runtime.SetFinalizer` so it'll anyway getting closed when it's gc'ed(which as mentioned might not happen until program exit). There's no need to provide your own finalizer.

Comment: @Nos yes I realize that. I guess I should include it in my answer but I'm on my phone.

Comment: It's really a bad practice to use `SetFinalizer`.  Take Dustin's answer instead: Use the `defer` keyword.  It is designed for resource cleanup.

Comment: @Kirakun i know but defer is not the same as SetFinalizer. At all. And defer is not the answer to the question above.

Answer (score 16):

You wouldn't do that in java, either.  The correct thing to do in java is to have a `finally` block that closes it somewhere near where you opened up.

You'd use a similar pattern in go with a `defer` function to do the cleanup.  For example, if you did this (java):

```
try {
  open();
  // do stuff
} finally {
  close();
}
```

In go, you'd do this:

```
open();
defer close();
// do stuff
```

Comment: Note that `defer f.close()` in go potentially ignores an error.  If you are writing to the file then that can be important.  See here https://groups.google.com/d/msg/golang-nuts/GOd-rmqwAME/bPpqFPh9xkkJ for how to do it properly.

Comment: Well, sure, but anyone expecting the garbage collector to close his files doesn't care much about reliability in the first place.  I generally don't care about errors on close because I generally don't have another choice.