# When to close a file?

Tags: file-io, go

Is necessary to close a file when you only want create it? I'm supposed that it's only necessary in case of reading or writing.

```
_, err := os.OpenFile(name, os.O_CREATE, 0640)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Will it work? Yes. The file will be created.

Should you do it? No. It is a bad idea in general even though you can get away with it sometimes.

Opening a file allocates resources like a file handle to your process. You should close it to free those resources. Otherwise they will be unavailable until the process dies.

Comment: But I'm not returning the file handler; note that I'm using `_, err`

Comment: Yes, so it is eligible to be garbage collected. That doesn't guarantee that it actually will be. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636817/google-go-equivalent-of-java-finalize-method

Answer (score 1):

When you create the file you also open it, so you should close it.